# How to move row to another row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to move one or two rows(with data) for e.g. from end to first position or from middle to end? With phpmyadmin with GUI there isn't option to moving rows.

Another question:
How to move one table to another table by copying data?

Answer (score 1):

Rows position in a resultset are determined by `ORDER BY` clause or by "chance" if it's not specified, so moving from a position to another in absolute has no meaning.

You can use `INSERT SELECT` statement to copy data from `table1` to `table2` if they have the same structure.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT *
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may copy data with help of a query:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
```